# ionic cordovarduino java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Im trying to connect usb camera to android mobile phone in ionic framework. im able to connect to device but serial.open is not working.

**Error:**

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=1   at
>   android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface.getEndpoint(UsbInterface.java:135)
>     at
>   com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.CdcAcmSerialDriver$CdcAcmSerialPort.open(CdcAcmSerialDriver.java:129)
>     at fr.drangies.cordova.serial.Serial$3.run(Serial.java:242)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)

**My Code:**

```
this.serial.requestPermission({
    vid: '1908',
    pid: '2311',
    driver: 'CdcAcmSerialDriver' 
})
.then(
    res => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(res));
        this.openSerial();
    },
    error => {
       alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
);


this.serial.open({
    baudRate: 19200,
    dataBits: 8,
    stopBits: 1,
    parity: 0,
    dtr: true,
    rts: true,
    sleepOnPause: false
})
```

---